# How to prevent unauthorized domain forwarding via Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, dns, phishing

An unauthorized domain unauthdomain.cf is forwarding to our domain ourdomain.com. We tried to stop this unauthorized domain from rendering our content/pages via nginx but the solution on http but didnt work on https.

To Catch non authorized domains on both http and https, we tried the below:

```
server{ 
listen 80 default_server; 
root /aaa/bbb/www/404; 
index index.html index.htm; 
location / { 
try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
} 
} 

server{ 
listen 443 default_server; 
root /aaa/bbb/www/404; 
index index.html index.htm; 
location / { 
try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
} 
}
```

But I received the error as

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to ourdomain.com. SSL received a 
record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: 
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

My Domain Non-SSL V-host:

```
server { 
listen 80; 
server_name ourdomain.com www.ourdomain.com; 
server_tokens off;
```

My Domain SSL V-host:

```
server { 
listen 443; 
server_name ourdomain.com; 

ssl on; 
ssl_certificate /myssl_crt_file; 
ssl_certificate_key /myssl_key_file; 

ssl_protocols SSLv2 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256HE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384HE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHAHE-RSA-AES256-SHA; 
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Any suggestions will greatly help!

Comment: Are you stating that your main `https` website has stopped working? The error message is ambiguous.

Comment: Our site is working normally. On doing the above settings, the hotlinking site is able to run on https, while on http, the hotlinking site is not able to fetch our pages.